# getting specific values from an object

Tags: arrays

(I am working with Angular but this is not an angular specific problem).I have a json object that i am trying to disect. I've been trying to get my head around this and have come up with a complicated script with nested for loops that isn't working. The object consists of 3 arrays. The first array is an array of fieldnames. The third array is an array of arrays that correspond to the field names like so:

```
object = {"fields" : [array], "type" : [array], "values" : [array]}
```

where:

```
fields = ["user","bananas","pies","apples","pears","mangos","date"]
values = [["Bongo","12","2","1","2","4","05-02-2015"], ["Mongo","12","23","15","22","43","05-02-2015"], ["Congo","15","32","21","23","44","06-02-2015"]]
```

What i want to do is count the amount of fruit that all users had on a specific date. for instance i want to know how many bananas all users had on "06-02-2015".

I can post my code, but i think that would only work confusing as it's probably wrong and redundant.

**update:**

I've tried the filter but can't get it to work because the values inside object.values don't have a name. So i think it should be something like this:

```
var fruits = $filter('filter')(object.value, {???[6] : "2015-04-29 00:00:00"}, true);
```

I'm not sure what the ??? should be.

**solved:**

simply removing the name did the trick.

```
var fruits = $filter('filter')(object.value, "2015-04-29 00:00:00", true);
```

Comment: This looks to me like it doesn't really have anything to do with Angular. Could you edit the question and make it clear whether you're having an issue displaying the data or instead calculating the sum?

Comment: it's not an 'angular' problem, true. Will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script should group the values by date:

```js
var fields = ["user","bananas","pies","apples","pears","mangos","date"];
var values = [["Bongo","12","2","1","2","4","05-02-2015"], ["Mongo","12","23","15","22","43","05-02-2015"], ["Congo","15","32","21","23","44","06-02-2015"]];
var result = {};
for (var j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
    if (!result.hasOwnProperty(values[j][fields.length - 1]))
            result[values[j][fields.length - 1]] = {};
    for (var i = 1; i < fields.length - 1; i++) {
        if (!result[values[j][fields.length - 1]][fields[i]]) 
            result[values[j][fields.length - 1]][fields[i]] = parseInt(values[j][i], 10);
        else
            result[values[j][fields.length - 1]][fields[i]] += parseInt(values[j][i], 10);
        
        
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter):

```
var fruits = $filter('filter')(object, {date: $choosenDate}, true);
```

Then, if you want to split fruit by type, you can use [angular.forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) to iterate on the nev `fruits` var

Comment: This seems like what I want but it won't work like this because the date attribute isn't actually in the same array as the corresponding value. i've updated my OP.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a lot simpler if the structure of the arrays wasn't bananas, so to speak.

```js
var fields = ["user","bananas","pies","apples","pears","mangos","date"];
var values = [["Bongo","12","2","1","2","4","05-02-2015"], ["Mongo","12","23","15","22","43","05-02-2015"], ["Congo","15","32","21","23","44","06-02-2015"]];

var date, dataArray, dateIndex = (fields.length - 1),
  dates = {};
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  dataArray = values[i];
  date = dataArray[dateIndex];
  dates[date] = dates[date] || {};
  for (j = 1; j < fields.length - 1; j++) {
    dates[date][fields[j]] = dates[date][fields[j]] || 0;
    dates[date][fields[j]] += Number(dataArray[j]);
  }
}


console.log(dates);
```

Comment: i know they arrays are weird, but it's what i'm dealing with at the moment.

Comment: Understood-that wasn't a criticism, but rather an attempt at humor.

Comment: still so new at this that i take everything seriously i guess :P